# How do I simplify $\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{5x^4}{48}+\frac{7x^6}{576}\dots}$ using long division?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The infinite series $\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{5x^4}{48}+\frac{7x^6}{576}\dots}$ is supposed to simplify to $1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{7x^4}{48}+\frac{19x^6}{576}\cdots$ but I don't know how this was calculated.

[Did I make an error](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=89F4F969EE9E09DF!47050&authkey=!APtBiR17C11BqWw&v=3&ithint=photo%2CJPG) or did Zill make an error on the $x^6$ term (I got $\frac{11}{576x^6}$.)

Comment: Actually, Zill's approach is basic, but very effective. It should work provided, that he improves his hand writing!. Simple errors are made when not working neatly in math. I lke Zill's approach by just using regular long division in a rather non- conformal way (That is, exponential terms go up instead of down...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that:
$$\frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{5x^4}{48}+\frac{7x^6}{576}+\ldots} = 1+a_2 x^2+a_4 x^4 + a_6 x^6 + \ldots $$
and multiply both sides by $1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{5x^4}{48}+\frac{7x^6}{576}+\ldots$. If, after that, we consider the coefficient of $x^2$ in both sides, we get $\frac{1}{2}+a_2=0$, so $a_2=-\frac{1}{2}$. If we consider the coefficient of $x^4$, we get $\frac{5}{48}+\frac{1}{2}a_2+a_4=0$, hence $a_4=\frac{7}{48}$. If we consider the coefficient of $x^6$, we get:
$$ \frac{7}{576}+\frac{5}{48}a_2 + \frac{1}{2}a_4 + a_6 = 0, $$
hence $\color{red}{a_6=-\frac{19}{576}}$.

Comment: Thanks! I'm picking your answer because although it's more cumbersome, I'll remember it because I understand it. I see what the other solution is doing but it's not obvious why it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I got

$$1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{7x^4}{48}-\frac{19x^6}{576}\cdots$$

Let

$$D = 1+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{5x^4}{48}+\frac{7x^6}{576}\dots,$$

your divisor.

First remainder is

$$R_1 = 1 - 1D = -\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{5x^4}{48} - \frac{7x^6}{576} + O(x^8).$$

Second remainder (for the $-x^2/2$ term) is

$$R_2 = R_1 - \left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)D = \frac{7x^4}{48} + \frac{23x^6}{576} + O(x^8).$$

Third remainder (for the $5x^4/48$ term) is

$$R_3 = R_2 - \left(\frac{7x^4}{48}\right)D = -\frac{19x^6}{576} + O(x^8),$$

which gives the last term.

Comment: oh, your right, Zill in his diff eq series solution made the typo on one line and then corrected it on the next step to -19. I'm glad some one knew how to do this because I don't know where to look. Probably in a number theory book?

Comment: I could've wasted all night trying to find out how to do this, sorry i can't give anyone points, my rep's not high enough

Comment: You mentioned long division.  That's all I did.  That's not so much number theory as arithmetic with expressions.  Do a Google search for *polynomial long division* to see some examples.  My solution may make more sense after seeing those.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, you now have enough reputation to vote up answers. :)